# Differences between KVR16N11H/8 and KVR16N11/8 memory except for height?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I accidentally ordered [KVR16N11/8](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/partsinfo.asp?root=&LinkBack=&ktcpartno=KVR16N11/8&id=1) instead of [KVR16N11H/8](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/partsinfo.asp?root=us&LinkBack=http://www.kingston.com&ktcpartno=KVR16N11H/8) and I'm wondering if I'm going to have compability issues with my [Intel DP67DE motherboard](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-board-dp67de.html).

When searching for compatible RAM on Kingstons site for that motherboard the `KVR16N11H/8` RAM was one of the compatible ones. The `KVR16N11/8` did not show up as compatible for that motherboard. **The only difference I can see is that they have different physical height, or am I missing something?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the datasheets ([KVR16N11H/8](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR16N11H_8.pdf), [KVR16N11/8](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR16N11_8.pdf)), the KVR16N11/8 has exactly the same height, so as far as the specs are concerned, there isn't any difference at all.

The KVR16N11/8 datasheet is four months older, so I guess the H is a newer revision.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't even know there are datasheets available, so I learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

I just used the online chat facility to communicate with a helpful Kingston Support Representative called Caterina.

Question: "Please could you tell me what the difference is between KVR16N11H/8 and KVR16N11/8?"

Answer: "I have just double checked the information with our R&D department. The only difference is that the module with the H (KVR16N11H/8) has a 30mm height. The other module (KVR16N11/8) may come with a 30mm height or with a standard or low profile height."

Thought I'd share this with you ;)